# How to make all uploaded YouTube videos as private

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

In my application I have upload the videos in YouTube using android mobile application,But I want to make all uploaded videos as private if there is any possible.

Comment: You should check YouTube documentation and some Google search.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply if there is any link for learn this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set **privacy status** of your video to **private** while uploading the video using **Youtube Data Api v3**. Code will be like this -

```
VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
status.setPrivacyStatus("private");
```

For more information visit

[Youtube Data Api V3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)

Comment: Thanks for your quickly i will check your code for using private.

Comment: This is working. But when we upload the videos as "public" with subscriber account the uploaded path will be like http://www.youtube.com/<<channel name>>. But when I upload videos as "private", the path will be like https://www.youtube.com/channel/<<some alphanumeric key>>/videos. Here the channel name is missing. What might be the issue?